# Javascript textbox update on simple addition

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have four texboxes with ids #a #b #c #d.
Suppose user enters the values for any three of the above boxes then the remaining textbox will show the sum of values entered in three boxes earlier.

For Example:
If user enters the values of #a #c & #d
the remaining textbox i.e. #b will show the sum of #a #b & #c

How can we implement this in Javascript or jquery?
I am using onkeyup() function but am not able to solve it.

Code Tried :

```
<input type="Number" id="a" onkeyup="check();" />
<input type="Number" id="b" onkeyup="check();"/>
<input type="Number" id="c" onkeyup="check();"/>
<input type="Number" id="d" onkeyup="check();"/>
    <script>
var a=Number($('#a').val());
var b=Number($('#b').val());
var c=Number($('#c').val());
var d=Number($('#d').val());
    Function check(){
    if (a!=null && b!=null && c!=null)
    {
        var sum1=a+b+c;
        Number($('#d').val(sum1));
    }
    else if (a!=null && b!=null && d!=null)
    {
        var sum2=a+b+d;
        Number($('#c').val(sum2));
    }
    else if (a!=null && c!=null && d!=null)
    {
        var sum3=a+c+d;
        Number($('#b').val(sum3));
    }
    else if (b!=null && c!=null && d!=null)
    {
        var sum4=b+c+d;
        Number($('#a').val(sum4));
    }
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Show us your code what you have tried in `onkeyup` function.

Comment: Try my answer Ankit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the following changes in your code.

1. Check the uppercase `F` in `Function check()`. It needs to be in lowercase `f` (i.e) `function check()`.
2. Check the `null` condition like this. `if (a && b && c)`
3. Put separate method for getting the updated `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` values and call that method in your `check` method.

**Code snippets:**

```js
var a, b, c, d;

function values() {
  a = Number($('#a').val());
  b = Number($('#b').val());
  c = Number($('#c').val());
  d = Number($('#d').val());
}

function check() {
  values();
  if (a && b && c) {
    var sum1 = a + b + c;
    $('#d').val(sum1);
  } else if (a && b && d) {
    var sum2 = a + b + d;
    $('#c').val(sum2);
  } else if (a && c && d) {
    var sum3 = a + c + d;
    $('#b').val(sum3);
  } else if (b && c && d) {
    var sum4 = b + c + d;
    $('#a').val(sum4);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="Number" id="a" onkeyup="check();" />
<input type="Number" id="b" onkeyup="check();" />
<input type="Number" id="c" onkeyup="check();" />
<input type="Number" id="d" onkeyup="check();" />
```

Comment: Thnxs it is what i want

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this? If you're using jQuery:

```
$("#b").keyup(function(){

    // Add a + b to total
    var a = parseInt($("#a").val());
    var b = parseInt($("#b").val());

    $("#total").text(a+b);
});

$("#c").keyup(function(){

    // Add a + b to total
    var a = parseInt($("#a").val());
    var b = parseInt($("#b").val());
    var c = parseInt($("#c").val());

    $("#d").val(a+b);
});
```

Edit: this just is a quick draft to give you an idea, not sure if it will work instantly.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<input type="Number" id="a"  >
<input type="Number" id="b" >
<input type="Number" id="c">
<input type="Number" id="d" >
```

JS:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
   $( 'input').keyup(function() {
           var a=Number($('#a').val());
var b=Number($('#b').val());
var c=Number($('#c').val());
var d=Number($('#d').val());


    if (a!=null && b!=null && c!=null)
    {
        var sum1=a+b+c;
        $('#d').val(sum1);
    }
    else if (a!=null && b!=null && d!=null)
    {
        var sum2=a+b+d;
        $('#c').val(sum2);
    }
    else if (a!=null && c!=null && d!=null)
    {
        var sum3=a+c+d;
        $('#b').val(sum3);
    }
    else if (b!=null && c!=null && d!=null)
    {
        var sum4=b+c+d;
      $('#a').val(sum4);
    }
    });
   });
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1c4pvamm/6/

Answer (score 0):

Challenge accepted!

A solution in VanillaJS. Works with different number of boxes.

4 Boxes

```
// Example with 4 boxes
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wpLdmxeh/2/

5 Boxes

```
// Example with 5 boxes
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wpLdmxeh/3/