# Getting the number of unfilled empty text boxes in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was trying to solve another person's jQuery question and ran into an issue of my own.

In order to solve this question, I need to determine the number of text boxes that are empty. I thought the best solution would be to use the `element[attribute='value']` selector but that didn't work.

```
alert($("input[val='']").length);
```

I always get 0, even when there are 3 other empty text boxes. Empty text boxes should have a value equal to an empty string.

Here is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/04gqaLog/

HTML

```
<input type="text" /></br>
<input type="text" /></br>
<input type="text" /></br>
<input type="text" />
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var sum = 0;
    var boxesFilled = 0;
    $("input").on("change", function() {
        sum += +$(this).val();
        boxesFilled += 1;
        alert($("input[val='']").length);
    });
});
```

Comment: This should work if your html input elements are changed to: <input type="text" value="" /> and your selector changes to input[value='']

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first issue is you are referring to the `value` attribute as `val`. Those are considered two **distinct** attributes.

The next issue is some input elements may not have a value attribute. Therefore, you will need to specifically check for that **or** check if the value is *falsey*

```
    var emptyInputs = $('input').filter(function() {
      return !$(this).val();
    });
    console.log(emptyInputs.length);
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var sum = 0;
  var boxesFilled = 0;
  $("input").on("change", function() {
    sum += +$(this).val();
    boxesFilled += 1;
    var emptyInputs = $('input').filter(function() {
      return !$(this).val();
    });
    console.log(emptyInputs.length);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" />
</br>
<input type="text" />
</br>
<input type="text" />
</br>
<input type="text" />
```

Comment: Many thanks. Simply using `$("input"[value='']")` doesn't work but using the `filter` function is genius. I never thought of that.

Comment: @RichardHamilton, believe it or not, I learned this lesson myself answering the same question, the same way :)

Comment: You should answer this question too. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32208397/javascript-textbox-update-on-simple-addition/32209087#32209087  Just change my answer a little. I couldn't have solved it without your help anyways